# How to transform a date according to locale

Tags: angular

I'm trying to change the date format on the basis of locale. For now my requirement is only two locales:

1. en-US (English)
2. de-De (German)

I tried few things but I'm getting this error:

> ERROR Error: Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date
> Angular 2
> transform ...
> ...

Here is template:

```
<button (click)="apply()"></button>
```

Here is my logic:

```
  primaryStartDateLabel: string;
  primaryEndDateLabel: string;
  secondaryStartDateLabel: string;
  secondaryEndDateLabel: string;

  parentLocale = "en-US";

  apply() {
    const primaryDateLabels = "01-01-2021,03-05-2021";
    const secondaryDateLabels = "01-01-2020,03-05-20210";
    this.extractDateLabels(primaryDateLabels, secondaryDateLabels);
  }

  extractDateLabels(primaryDateLabels, secondaryDateLabels) {
    const primaryLabels = primaryDateLabels.split(",");
    const secondaryLabels = secondaryDateLabels.split(",");
    console.log("after split ", primaryLabels);
    console.log("after split ", secondaryLabels);
    this.primaryStartDateLabel = this.myFormatDate(primaryLabels[0]);
    this.primaryStartDateLabel = this.transform(
      this.primaryStartDateLabel,
      this.parentLocale
    );
    this.primaryEndDateLabel = this.myFormatDate(primaryLabels[1]);
    this.primaryEndDateLabel = this.transform(
      this.primaryEndDateLabel,
      this.parentLocale
    );
    this.secondaryStartDateLabel = this.myFormatDate(secondaryLabels[0]);
    this.secondaryStartDateLabel = this.transform(
      this.secondaryStartDateLabel,
      this.parentLocale
    );
    this.secondaryEndDateLabel = this.myFormatDate(secondaryLabels[1]);
    this.secondaryEndDateLabel = this.transform(
      this.secondaryEndDateLabel,
      this.parentLocale
    );
  }

  transform(value: string, locale: string) {
    console.log("looking_1 ", value, locale);
    let format;
    if (locale === "en-US") {
      format = "MM-dd-y";
    } else {
      format = "mediumDate";
    }
    console.log("looking_1 ", format);
    return formatDate(value, format, locale);
  }

  myFormatDate(value: string) {
    const stringValue = new Date(
      moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    );
    return stringValue.toDateString();
  }
```

When locale is en-Us the date should be like: "03-23-2021"

But When locale is de-De or something else the date should be like: "03.23.2021"

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c14tja?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) (with moment related error).

Please help me achieve my ojective.

P.S: Due to some restrictions I cannot use Date pipe from angular. I've to create something customizable from my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify moment import. `import moment from "moment";`

Don't need extra variable assignment `moment = _moment;`

Finally call `moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD")`

**Edit:**
Import moment locales `import 'moment/min/locales';`

change the `parentLocale` value to `us` or `de` and see the magic.

The final working result at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c14tja-5gxrbg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: you fixed the moment problem bro. thanks for that but i need to change the locale. please help me with that also.

Comment: Locale implemented. Please recheck.

Comment: please point out my mistakes if youve time

Comment: Welcome. I actually don't know your clear requirements. So, more detail may help to understand.